# Getting the short cut name

Tags: c#

I have one program, the exe is called main.exe. when main.exe is excuted. I allowed the user to be able to create a shortcut off main.exe. But when the user can create any name for the shortcut. so if the user is selecting the shortcut. I need the name of this short cut. not the program its pointing to

Comment: when main.exe is excuted... what happens? Please edit the question as it is not clear.

Comment: Why do you want to know that?  Also you assume your program is always launched from a Desktop shortcut.  What about when they use the Start menu?  Search?

Comment: so I can look up the shortcut name on the database and load a specific set of data for a specific short cut

Comment: That sounds like a terrible way to implement program customisation. It's somewhat prone to error

Comment: Then, how would you let a user create their own short cut and every time they want to load a short cut, how will you know which one they are loading???

Comment: You don't.  Either have your program accept program arguments or deploy multiple boot-strap apps that determine the profile to load

Comment: Surely there is a way to get the title of the app title selected in the initialize.

Comment: Another option would be to show some kind of menu on startup that the user selects a value from, rather than them selecting a shortcut.

Comment: A shortcut does not change the name of the application it points to.

Comment: Your simplest solution would be to pass the .exe parameters, as simple as that. You can then create as many shortcuts as you'd like, each with their own parameters being used for identification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't getting the shortcut name from running exe. Application does not receive information about shortcut used to launch it.

You can use command line arguments and/or current working directory to configure your application (both can be set via properties of a shortcut).

Comment: This is what I want to do. the problem is getting the shortcut information out. I can store it in the comment section of a shortcut

Comment: I used shortcut.arguments and I save  the shortcut name when I do this. It works. thanks